# Is it covex function?$J_{new}(u)=\int_{\Omega} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda_if(x)u_i(x)dx$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a function such as
$$J(u)=\int_{\Omega} \sum_{i=1}^{N} f(x)u_i(x)dx$$
where $f(x):\Omega \to R$, $0 \le u_i(x) \le 1,\sum_i u_i(x)=1$

Given that $J(u)$ is a convex function w.r.t $u$. Now I will multiple my $J(u)$ function with coefficient $\lambda=[\lambda_1..\lambda_N]$ such as
 $$J_{new}(u)=\int_{\Omega} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda_if(x)u_i(x)dx$$

where $0 \le \lambda_i \le 1$.

My question is that $J_{new}(u)$ is whether convex or non-convex function w.r.t $u$? If it is convex function w.r.t $u$, please prove it? Thanks in advance

I think that it is still convex function w.r.t $u$

Answer (score 0):

The argument $u$ is linear in $J$ and $J_{new}$.

Comment: Certainly linear functions are convex, but I don't take your point here.  If you can explain in greater detail, it would greatly improve this Answer.

Comment: Multiplication is linear, sum is linear, integral is linear ...

Comment: So, the answer is convex or nonconvex function in term of $u$

Comment: @user2938494 it is convex in $u$. Like .@hardmath stated linearity implies convexity.